# Can MediaWiki use more than one MySQL database?

Tags: mediawiki

Can mediawiki use more than one database?  My provider has a limit of 6Gb per database.  Can I split a 7Gb mediawiki installation over two databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [revision text can be moved to a separate DB](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:External_Storage).